# Checking for numeric with decimal

Tags: bash

I have an expression like the following:

```
echo “B1500.00” | egrep '^[(-|+)]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$'
```

I am checking for numeric with a decimal and if there is something that isn't numeric in the field, I want an error.

It appears to not error out with the above expression.  The expression comes back as being a number if I have an actual number like 1500.00 or -1500.00.  I'm sure there is just something I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

Those quotes are unicode characters, which are being passed to `egrep` as part of the expression to match.

Also, the first character class is probably not quite what you want, try:

```
echo B1500.00 | egrep '^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$'
```

which does not have a match while

```
echo 1500.00 | egrep '^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$'
```

does match `1500.00`

The character class I offered will match just `+` or `-` while your original one would also match `|` and opening and closing parens, which I think is probably not what you wanted.

As Costas pointed out you can tell `egrep` you want to match the entire line and ignore the start and end anchors like so:

```
echo 1500.00 | egrep -x '[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?'
```

Comment: open and close parenthesis are also good to include as it covers such things as `-(-5)`, however the pipe is best left out. Might also be good to include `[/* ]` so that you could have equations if that was desirable.

Comment: @Dave the parens for that might be good, but the ones in the OP pattern wouldn't match parens around the number, it would only match parens or a `+` or `-` or `|`, so it would have matched, say `)5` but not `-(5`

Comment: Eric: replacing the first `?` ("exactly 0 or 1 matches") with a `*` ("0 or more matches") would fix that - but it would still allow bogus non-numbers like `)5` or `()-+5`.